# Different header style for a specific view

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

My current Rails project requires the home page to have a header that's different from the rest of the page's views. The only difference is the style applied to it (bigger logo, bigger search bar...). I have a solution that works, but it feels a little "dirty" and I'd like to know if there's a more elegant way of styling specific pages.

So far, I'm doing this on the application's layout:

```
body class="#{controller_name} #{action_name}"
```

So I can do this on mi css:

```
#headerWrapper {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  ...
}
...
.catalog.index {
  #headerWrapper {
    font-size: 2em;
      ...
  }
}
```

But whenever  I make a change to the base style here, the index page's layout may be affected and I'm forced to "undo" whatever change I've made (i.e. if I change the font size, I have to adapt it accordingly on the .catalog.index part).

Any thoughts on the most elegant way of handling this issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a second layout page for the homepage which references the specific look and feel css classes you want and then direct the controller and specific action to render that new layout i.e:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  layout 'signin', :only => [:show]

  ......

end
```

More information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html (the bit specific to my suggesting is from 2.2.12.1 onwards)